# Is there a convention about how to make it easy or accessible for customers transfer money to an overseas bank account by email?

Tags: bank-account, international-transfer

I don't reside in Israel and I don't have a business associated with the Israeli tax authorities but I have an online business aimed primarily to Hebrew speakers which the vast majority of them reside in Israel;

I desire to get payments by bank transfer so I have created the RTF file below which a customer should email to its bank branch, asking them to transfer money overseas as payment, but my problem is that most customers don't usually use email to make bank transfers but rather by banking smartphone applications which at least some of them don't allow overseas transfers.

Is there a convention about how to make it easy or accessible for customers transfer money to an overseas bank account by email (as with a file similar to the one below)?

[An ordinal Hebrew RTF file example (my bank account details omitted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM8FW.png)

An English translation of the linked RTF file:

> ### A request for an overseas bank transfer
>
> **I, member of the bank by these details:**
>
> Name:
>  Identity card number:
>  Bank branch:
>  Bank account number:
>  Email:
>   Phone number:
>
> **Kindly request to transfer money by these details:**
>
> Currency:
>  Sum in digits:
>  Sum in words:
>
> **To the overseas bank account by these details:**
>
> State:
>  Bank:
>  Bank code (IBAN/SWIFT/other)
>  Branch:
>   Account name:
>  Account number:
>  Transfer purpose:
>
> **If a telephone confirmation is required, please don't hesitate to contact me**
>
> Best regards

---

<sub>If I have asked a bad question, please comment and suggest how to improve it; I tried my best and will try further if I need.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own queston: "most customers don't usually use email to make bank transfers".

If your bank allows "fund transfer" through email instructions, an attacker could just get the password of the email from sources listed at https://haveibeenpwned.com/ , login to your email account, then instruct the Bank to transfer away all your money.

Some banks accept an instruction similar to your format, but with a handwritten signature and physically mailed to the branch of the bank. However, as a non-standard form of the bank was used, the Bank would charge extra processing fee, and it is impossible for you to prepare all possible Forms of each bank.

There is no convention on teaching how a customer enters information on a smartphone App, and it is not your responsbility to teach them. If they entered information wrongly, the transfer gets bounced and both of you lose only time, and you can refuse to deliver service until you actually received the funds.

Comment: I thank you dearly for this answer, base64; I think it would be simpler for me to open a bank account in Israel remotely with the help of a lawyer (I can do that as I hold Israeli citizenship and might visit there soon); furthermore, I might just use PayPal for a while --- I have used it in the past and can use it again (although, somewhat reluctantly); kindly !